# Extract data from mainly unstructured sets and derive risk metrics out of those

Tags: machine-learning, probability, unsupervised-learning, supervised-learning

I have the following question (this was a real life problem):

**Q:** Extract data from mainly unstructured sets and derive risk metrics out of those. From what you know or imagine about the data available in the art market and/or other passion asset markets, how would you go about in identifying relevant data, collect it, clean it and to analyse the data to come up with a model that predicts the probability of a crash in the art market over the next 12 months.

**My Answer:**

1. Understand the Business problem : Crash in the art market over the next 12 mont
2. Extract and explore the data and become familiar with it using web scrapping. Retrieve datasets from previous researches to compare. See the current economic situation and the predictions for next year.
3. Implements an unsupervised technique like clustering to find structure within the data, add labels, and see how many groups there are. K-means clustering is a good method
4. Prepare the data for modeling by detecting outliers, treating missing values, transforming variables, encoding, scaling, etc.
5. Use a supervised technique to generate predictions, I would recommend starting with a simple model and make your way up using diagnostics and cross validation. Multiple Linear Regression is a good starting point or time-series.

The main problem I have with what I wrote is:

1. I don't know if I can use both Unsupervised and Supervised models with the same data, my idea of unsupervised is that it will organise unstructured data in a way that will allow me to use a supervised technique, but I am not sure if that is the right idea.
2. They are asking me to get a probability as my final outcome, so I am not confident that a Regression model or time-series would get me the answer since they just output concrete number, like the price of something or quantity of something. I have the idea that I could use Naive Bayes Classifier, but I am not sure.
   Thank you!

Comment: Best to change your title to something informative about the nature of the question.

Comment: Noted! Thank you!

Comment: did you get art market prices data somehwre?

Comment: No, this is a simulation scenario given, just to assess the way you approach the problem